# Find the minimum of $q$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given $\displaystyle p,q\in\mathbb N, \frac p q=0.123456789...$(i.e. the first 9 digits after decimal point are $123456789$). Find the minimum of $q$.

I *guessed* the answer to be $111111111$ as $\displaystyle\frac {123456789} {999999999}=0.\dot{1}2345678\dot{9}$, but I'm not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: There more digits after that.

Comment: @julien: Just the first *nine* digits are known, the digits after that can be anything.

Comment: @Inceptio They can't be anything, because it has to be a rational number, if I understand the question. So the decimal expansion either terminates, or is eventually periodic.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be a rational number. But what values after those nine digits makes the value of $q$ minimum. $0's$, of course.

Comment: @Inceptio No. For instance $123456789/10^9=0.123456789<123456789/999999999=0.12345678912$, yet $10^9>999999999$.

Comment: Actually calculator is not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the magic algorithm which Hagen von Eitzen used to compute the answer.
This method is extremely elegant, and is derived from Farey sequences.

To shorten the computation, I will solve the analagous question of finding the smallest $q$ such that $\frac{p}{q}$ has decimal expansion $.789....$.

Let $\alpha = \frac{789}{1000}$; we are looking for rational numbers close to $\alpha$ with small denominators.  (In general, $\alpha$ can be any positive real number.)

Start with the two fractions $\frac01$ and $\frac10$.
Note that $\frac01 < \alpha < \frac10$.
*Add the numerators* and *add the denominators* to get the fraction
$\frac{0 + 1}{1 + 0} = \frac11$.  Of the three fractions we have listed so far ($\frac01, \frac11,$ and $\frac10$), take the two that are on either side of $\alpha$, i.e. $\frac01$ and $\frac11$.

We have the two fractions $\frac01$ and $\frac11$, with $\frac01 < \alpha < \frac11$.
Add the numerators and denominators to get $\frac{0 + 1}{1 + 1} = \frac12$.  Of the three fractions $\frac01$, $\frac12$, and $\frac11$, $\alpha$ is between $\frac12$ and $\frac11$, so take these two.

We have the two fractions $\frac12$ and $\frac11$.
Add the numerators and denominators to get $\frac{1 + 1}{2 + 1} = \frac23$.  Of the three fractions $\frac12$, $\frac23$, $\frac11$, $\alpha$ is between
$\frac23$ and $\frac11$, so take these two.

You can see where this is going.  Next we get the pairs of fractions $\frac34$ and $\frac11$, then $\frac34$ and $\frac45$, then $\frac79$ and $\frac45$, then $\frac{11}{14}$ and $\frac45$, then $\frac{15}{19}$ and $\frac{4}{5}$.
We stop because $\frac{15}{19}$ has decimal expansion $.789....$ (it is the first of the fractions we have listed).  **This is the answer**.  No matter what decimal expansion you want ($.123456789$ in your case), this method will *always* eventually give you the fration $\frac{p}{q}$ with minimum $q$.

Answer (score 8):

The smallest $q$ is $q=10989019$ corresponding to $$\frac pq=\frac{1356669}{10989019}=0.12345678900000081899940294943524986\ldots$$
To see this, note that
$$ \frac ab=\frac{1356659}{10988938}=0.1234567889999925379504370668029977\ldots$$
is too small and
$$\frac cd=\frac{10}{81}=0.12345679012345679012345679012345679\ldots$$
is too big.
For any fraction with $\frac ab<\frac pq<\frac cd$, we have
$$\frac pq-\frac ab=\frac{bp-aq}{bq}>0\qquad\frac cd-\frac pq=\frac{cq-dp}{dq}>0,$$
hence $$ bp-aq\ge 1\qquad cq-dp\ge 1$$
and finally (because $bc-ad=1$)
$$ q=(bc-ad)q=d(bp-aq)+b(cq-dp)\ge b+d=10989019.$$

Comment: how have you reach at this $q?$

Comment: And how's it the minimum value?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Quick and dirty PARI/GP code: ` a=0;b=1;c=1;d=1; while(1, m=a+c;n=b+d;if(m/n<0.123456789,a=m;b=n,if(m/n>=0.12345679,c=m;d=n,print(m/n);return)); m/n`

Comment: To see where the magic comes from, look up Farey sequences.

Comment: And then $b+d$ works because of $(a+c)/(b+d)$...Very nice. A big part of the challenge is to come up with $a,b,c,d$. How many such tuples can we find? Can this be done without computer help? I forgot everything I ever knew about Farey sequences.

Comment: @julien:  I don't think so using the Farey sequence.  The problem is that $\frac {10}{81}$ is so close.  The denominator only increases by $81$ each time, so it will take something like $135700$ steps.  But it only takes four steps of the continued fraction, so that would be doable by hand.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you. Sorry but I can't see how to do that with continued fractions.

Comment: @julien:  it doesn't seem to work too well, either.  The next approximant after $\frac {10}{81}$ is $\frac {1356659}{10988938}$ in the continued fraction approximation [0;8,9,1,135665,1]. This doesn't seem to fit the Wikipedia article on [best rational approximations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_rational_approximation#Best_rational_approximations)

Comment: Actually calculator is not allowed.